# Using an obfuscator with OSGi declarative services

Tags: maven, osgi, obfuscation

I'm trying to use ProGuard from Maven to obfuscate my OSGi program. I am also using the SCR plugin to handle declarative services.

Unfortunately, ProGuard obfuscates all names in the classes but does not readily understand the relationship with the serviceComponents.xml file.

I should be able to write a program that uses the ProGuard obfuscation dictionary to fix this myself, but I'm wondering if there's something already out there.

In other words:

- If you are using OSGi declarative services, how do you obfuscate with ProGuard and Maven?
- And otherwise, well, how do you obfuscate at all? I'm flexible in terms of obfuscators and build systems...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ready-made solution that I'm aware of.

I think the best approach is to manually or automatically parse your service component declarations to extract all relevant class and method names and use the ProGuard `keepnames` options on these classes and methods.

Comment: Tanks so much. That's also the conclusion I got too, so we patched together a maven plugin for it. Given how long this question has been open, I suspect there really is no better way...

Answer (score 0):

The following proguard configuration helps you

```
#Keep all annotations, exceptions.
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Exceptions
#Keep all interfaces. This is required to run OSGi services.
-keep public interface *
#Keep all Component classes
-keep @org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component class *
#Kepp all Component classes member functions with OSGi specific annotations
-keepclassmembers @org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component class * {
   #Keep all methods with annotatios Reference.
   @org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference *;
   #Keep all methods with annotatios Activate.
   @org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate *;
}
```